# Text parameter input with date validation

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I want to allow user to input a date as a parameter in my report.

I'm using `datetime` type for a parameter (so it shows a datepicker). After I change region of my PC to "United Kingdom", it show correct format "dd/mm/yyyy", but when I view it on web portal the format is wrong: it show me "mm/dd/yyyy". Note that my browser language already set to "en-GB".

So, I'm thinking that if I create in text box, I need validation for it. I have done some research, and implemented the following VB code in report properties's code tab:

```vb
function CheckDateParameters(Dateas date) as Integer
    Dim msg as String

    If IsDate(Date)    Then 
        msg="correct format"
    else
        msg="invalid date format"
    End If

     If msg <> "" Then
        MsgBox(msg, 16, "Report Validation")
        Err.Raise(6,Report)                    'Raise an overflow
     End If
End Function
```

To call the function I do:

```
=Code.CheckDateParameters(Parameters!from.Value)
```

This function works if the date format is correct, but it does not work if the format is wrong. (I am not familiar with VB language.)

What is the proper way to do the validation? Is it on the SSRS side, or should I do it in my stored procedure?

Comment: Is the date returned by the date picker incorrect, or are you just bothered by how it's formatted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you are validateing a Date if it where a date you shoulden't have to validate it at all. Change it to a string insted.
And try not to use "Date" as you variable name.

```
Function CheckDateParameters(Dates As String) As Integer
        Dim msg As String

        If IsDate(Dates) Then
            msg = "correct format"
        Else
            msg = "invalid date format"
        End If

        If msg <> "" Then
            MsgBox(msg, 16, "Report Validation")
            'Err.Raise(6, Report)                    'Raise an overflow
        End If
    End Function
```